# How do you change selectedIndex in GridView and update

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a gridview:

```
            <asp:GridView ID="grv_existingEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                OnRowCommand="grv_existingEmployee_RowCommand" 
                onrowcancelingedit="grv_existingEmployee_RowCancelingEdit" 
                onrowdeleted="grv_existingEmployee_RowDeleted" 
                onrowdeleting="grv_existingEmployee_RowDeleting" 
                onrowediting="grv_existingEmployee_RowEditing">
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="but_delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
                            <asp:Button ID="but_edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="but_cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
            </asp:GridView>
```

And I am trying to make it so when a user click on the button, I change the selectedIndex, here is my code:

```
    protected void grv_existingEmployee_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
        string currentCommand = e.CommandName;
        int currentRowIndex = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        if (currentCommand == "Edit") {
            grv_existingEmployee.SelectedIndex = currentRowIndex;
        }
        if (currentCommand == "Delete") {
            grv_existingEmployee.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        if (currentCommand == "Cancel") {
            grv_existingEmployee.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        grv_existingEmployee.DataSource = myDataSource
        grv_existingEmployee.DataBind();
    }
```

Unfortunately this does not set the selected index, any ideas?

EDIT:  On further testing, they do change the selected index, but only on 2nd postback.

Comment: Does your code enter those if blocks?  Because that looks like it should be setting the SelectedIndex of the GridView.

Comment: Yup, they definitely enter the if block, not change though.

Comment: Wait, they do change it, but I have to post back twice.

Comment: Can you show the code where you originally databind your GridView?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that

```
grv_existingEmployee.SelectedIndex = currentRowIndex;
```

is not enough, what fixed it is to also add this:

```
grv_existingEmployee.EditIndex = currentRowIndex;
```